# Terminal/SSH : How can i track how many people are accessing my site at the moment live?

Tags: ssh, terminal, live

I want to connect to ssh and type in a command that will show me live updates such as their ip address as they enter my site. is that possible? simply see what page an ip address entered or just the ip of a person that connected to the site.

Live meaning i see the list updated as it happens.

Comment: Should be migrated to [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -f /path/to/your/access.log
```

Usually reading the log is pretty useless though.

Comment: Thank you. I was just curious to see it. It's exciting in a way.